# style.visibility not working in FireFox

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am having an aspx page with a panel. I am using the panel as to show a messagebox. The panel id is "panMessage". The panel contains a button label "Hide". I am showing the panel using code behind but need to close the panel with JS when user clicks on Hide button. I have attached the following code with onclick event of the button -

```
onclick="javascript:(<%=panMessage.ClientID%>).style.visibility='hidden';"
```

the click event works perfectly in IE but not in FireFox. I have googled and changed the code as -

```
onclick="javascript:(<%=panMessage.ClientID%>).style.display='none';"
```

but still the code is not working i.e. the panel is not going to hide in FireFox although it works in IE using this new code also.

Could someone guide me whats wrong i have done?

Thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: Show us the rendered HTML --> run your page, view source, copy/paste relevant HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem lies with `(<%=panMessage.ClientID%>)`.

```
onclick="(<%=panMessage.ClientID%>).style.display='none';"
```

When rendered would give something like:

```
onclick="(panMessage_1).style.display='none';"
```

You should put something like:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('<%=panMessage.ClientID%>').style.display='none';"
```

Comment: Thank all of you my friends! You guys are genius. The code is working fine.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `visibility hidden` and `display none` are not the same. The former will make the element consume the same space as it would have, if it would've been visible, whereas the latter won't. `display: none` is synonymous to `visibility: hidden; position: absolute;`

Other than that, your problem is probably due to the way you access your element. Try changing to the following:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('<%=panMessage.ClientID%>').style.display='none';"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

`document.getELementById ( "<%=panMessage.ClientID%>" )` to retrieve the element and then try setting the display or visibility attribute.

Set the display attribute to none so that the control won't take the space.

Answer (score 1):

We'd really need to see the actual HTML output to be able to debug it for you.

The correct output should look something like this:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('panMessage').style.display='none';"
```

Note that you don't need `javascript:` in the event handlers.